# About $K_{3,3}$ being planar or not

Tags: graph-theory, solution-verification, planar-graphs

I wanted to propose a “proof” that graph $K_{3,3}$ is not planar.
Lets suppose it is planar, then by Euler’s theorem  $V-E+F=2$. Now since $V=6$ and edges $E=9$ , so $F=5$. Now there cannot be a 3-cycle, since in this case two vertices that were not supposed to be would be connected (this is not hard to prove but i will omit). Now $K_{3,3}$ is connected , since we can access to any vertice by jumping around(this is also not hard to prove i think). Now this graph must have cycles, since otherwise graph would be a tree but it isnt since $V-1$ aint $E.$ So there is a cycle , and this cycle must contain 2 vertices that are not connected directly to each other. There can be 3 choose 2 ways to form such cycles whcih means we would have 3 cycles which could produce 4 faces but we needed 5 faces, so that is contradictory.

Comment: Why are there $^3C_2$ ways to form these cycles? By my calculation, there are $(^3C_2)^2 = 9$ $4$-cycles in $K_{3,3}$ (you can freely choose $2$ of the $3$ vertices from each of the partitions, and you'll form a unique $4$-cycle).

Answer (score 1):

A fast argument to see that there are no $3$-cycles: $K_{3,3,}$ is bipartite, hence every face has an even number of edges, or at least four edges. After that, $F$ faces means at least $4F$ face-edge incidences, which means at least $2F$ edges. This already contradicts  $E=9$ and the  $F=5$ you obtained from Euler.

Comment: But could you say my approach is also true? Tbh i am in abet thats why i am asking for verification

Comment: @MehemmedYusifov Betting is certainly one of the more novel reasons to practice mathematics...

Comment: Ah , no I didn’t meant to decrease the reputation of maths . I like it a lot , its just a bet in which i wanted to instil some math love to the other guy.but yeah , i also wanted to win tho :D

Comment: @MehemmedYusifov No judgement! I just thought it was amusing. :-)